# How do I deploy Polymer3 App to GH Pages?

Tags: polymer, github-pages, polymer-3.x

I have created a polymer3 app using the Polymer CLI. I cannot seem to configure the polymer.json file properly so that when I deploy to GH pages everything loads correctly.

At the moment my polymer.json looks like this:

```
{
"entrypoint": "index.html",
  "shell": "src/site-app/site-app.js",
  "sources": [
    "src/site-app/**",
    "package.json",
    "css/**",
    "js/**"
  ],
  "extraDependencies": [
    "manifest.json",
    "node_modules/@webcomponents/**",
    "node_modules/@polymer/**",
    "node_modules/@fabricelements/**",
    "node_modules/web-animations-js/**"
  ],
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "npm": true,
  "lint": {
    "rules": [
      "polymer-3"
    ]
  },
  "builds": [{
    "preset": "es6-unbundled"
  }]
}
```

And the Errors I see in my Dev Console on Chrome are the following
﻿

```
web-animations-next-lite.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
web-animations.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
webcomponents-loader.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
8
website.github.io/:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

How can I fix my polymer.json so I will properly deploy to GH Pages?

Answer (score 0):

polymer.json is only the configuration for polymer build. Github Pages wont download or host anything for you except whats in your repo. So you need load anything not in your repo (npm dependencies) from a cdn like https://cdnjs.com .